# ESLint couldn't find the config "airbnb-base" to extend from

Tags: node.js, eslint

in folder1, i did "npm install", run "eslint --ext .js .", all good.

Then i copied all the subfolder/files from folder1 to folder2, including .eslintrc, .jest, .npmrc, package.json, package-lock.json.
After npm install, i got this

```
> eslint --ext .js .


Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.32.0

ESLint couldn't find the config "airbnb-base" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.
```

How can this happen ? how to fix this pls ? The eslint in folder1 has the same version.

Answer (score 1):

We have used "root": true, as per https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3003522#comment-12796773 in our .eslintrc.js.

The file looks like below,

```
module.exports = {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, for folder2, the package.json did miss eslint-config-airbnb-base. Added it and worked.
Not sure why folder1 worked, maybe got from its parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete '*.eslintrc*' in the father of the folder2!